# alt keys broken after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 20.04

I recently upgraded to 20.04 LTS from 18.04 LTS and now both my left and right alt keys are not working when I try to use them for any keyboard shortcuts. I had no issues before upgrading. My keyboard mapping hasn't changed since the update (Macintosh UK).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit updated with xmodmap output

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0xcc),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Comment: What does `xmodmap` tell about Alt? Then you could try `xev` to find out what the key actually do.

Comment: @jarno thanks - have updated original post with xmodmap output. Looks like the key is triggering ISO_Level3_Shift from xev output.

Comment: Oh, the table shows it knows only left alt key. Have you tried if setting different keyboard model helps?

Comment: I've tried setting several different varations of the english language layout in the settings if that's what you're referring to? However this didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Try to find setting for keyboard model. It is different thing than keyboard layout.

Comment: resolved by changing the keyboard model via `dpkg-reconfigure` - thanks @jarno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this by changing the keyboard model via `dpkg-reconfigure` which then gave options to map the alt key which I could not figure out how to do using the keyboard settings in the GUI.